# Dynamic prop binding from parent to child

Tags: vue.js

So I'm having a headache since yesterday on this. I'd like to have some kind of two way binding of data. I want for my array `data(): exploredFields` be able to update the values of the children components. But the update is called from the child.

Here is my parent component.

```js
<div>
    <button @click="resetMinefield(rows, mineCount)">RESET</button>
</div>
<div class="minefield">
    <ul class="column" v-for="col in columns" :key="col">
        <li class="row" v-for="row in rows" :key="row">
            <Field
                    :field="mineFields[(row + (col - 1) * rows) - 1].toString()"
                    :id="(row + (col - 1) * rows) - 1"
                    :e="exploredFields[(row + (col - 1) * rows) - 1]" // This doesn't update the child !!!
                    @update="exploreField"
            />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

...

<script>
    import Field from "@/components/Field";

    export default {
        name: "Minesweeper",
        components: {
            Field,
        },
        created() {
            this.resetMinefield(this.rows, this.mineCount);
        },
        data() {
            return {
                rows: 7,
                columns: 7,
                mineCount: 5,
                mineFields: [],
                exploredFields: [],
            }
        },
        methods: {
            exploreField(index) {
                this.exploredFields[index] = true;
            },
            resetMinefield(fieldSize, mineCount) {
               // Updates this.mineFields
               // Passes data properly to the child
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

And here is a child component. On @click it updates self `data: explored` and parents `data: exploredFields`. But the dynamic binding for `props: e` does not work.

```js
<template>
    <div :class="classObject" @click="changeState">
        {{ field }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "Field",
        data() {
            return {
                explored: false,
            }
        },
        props: {
            id: {
                type: Number,
                default: -1,
            },
            field: {
                type: String,
                default: 'X',
            },
            e: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            changeState() {
                this.$emit("update", this.id);
                this.explored = true;
            }
        },
        computed: {
            classObject: function() {
                // Stuff here
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

I also tried to do dynamic binding for data `:explored` instead of props `:e`, but no effect there too. It seams that it doesn't want to update because I'm calling the update from the child. And even I can see the data changing, it is not passed back to child dynamically

Comment: You don't appear to be using `e` anywhere in the `Field` component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a common Vue [change detection caveat](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays).

> Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array:
>
> 1. When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`

This...

```js
this.exploredFields[index] = true
```

won't be reactive. Try this instead

```js
this.$set(this.exploredFields, index, true)
```

Comment: OMG yes! Thank you soooo much! I think I will remember this one for a long time :)

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need is a watcher inside your child component, on the prop "e"

```
watch: {
  e(newValue){
    this.explored = newValue
  }
}
```

Everything else looks fine to me, once you click on the field you are emitting an event and youre listening to that in the parent.

Comment: Well if I watch e that never gets updated that doesn't do much. I can watch explored data, but I cannot assign a value to this.e, because of data mutation